# KNP Paginator how to provide next record to jQuery

Tags: jquery, symfony, knppaginator

I have a set of items and user can select/deselect them. In case of deselect, I am using jQuery to remove the item from DOM.
Is it possible to have next item in paginator, like this I can add it to the DOM?

Comment: If you really want to do that you will need to prefetch the next page using javascript - just call the url with the next page in the request, then parse what you got. I could give you better info if you would show us some code

Comment: Thanks, I don't really need next page, but next record. I don't have any code, regarding this as I don't know how to do. My code is just querying DB and paginate it using the bundle. What can help you to help me?

Comment: @Alexander In fact I thought about the beginning of your comment "If you really want to do that" meaning that maybe I should not. So I won't as it's preferable for the user to go to next page when he/she has finished. Thanks